# TryParse Invalid Arguments

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a NUnit test searching for numbers within a string. I'm using TryParse but it gave me a this error: Error1: The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string, out int)' has some invalid arguments.

Could you guys tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
[Test]
public void ThenSearchForBrittanyShouldFindOneUser()
{
    var searchresult = LuceneFullTextSearch.SuggestSimilar("brit123", 1).ToArray();


    int num = 0;
    foreach (var result in searchresult)
    {

        if (result = int.TryParse(searchresult, out num))
        {
            searchresult.ShouldNotBeEmpty();
            searchresult.ShouldContain("Brittany");
            searchresult.Should().Count.NoMoreThan(1);
        }
        else
        {
            searchresult.ShouldNotBeEmpty();
            searchresult.Equals(num);
```

Comment: First you dont want to assign anything in a conditional. Just do int.TryParse(string,out int) in your conditional or you look like a nub. I would use result and not searchresult

Comment: `searchResult` looks like enumerable, not a string. This seems like a typo error more than anything. `foreach (var result in searchResult)` => I'm betting `result` should be your string input into int.TryParse (and then you also wouldn't use it as the `TryParse` method's return value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`searchresult` is an array, not a string; you want `result` there instead.

Also, you can't have an assignment in an `if` conditional, so your syntax is wrong anyway. `TryParse` already returns a bool, so you should try:

```
    if (int.TryParse(result, out num))
    {
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (int.TryParse(result, out num))
```